# Is there a place for a database in a Redux / React Application?

Tags: reactjs, redux

When building a redux / react application, do you still need to use a database to store data or is it OK for everything to just go into the redux store?

If a database is needed, where is the best place to make the database calls?

Comment: Redux just manages your frontend application's state. It doesn't persist data.

Comment: Redux only saves state for front-end application's state, which means that it's gone after page refresh, to persist it, you still need to save that state in database, most likely using standard methods, like calls to REST API

Comment: thanks a lot. i'm a beginner and i did not get this.

Comment: Hi joe, if using redux persist, will still need to use a backend database then?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is typically a case to be made for serializing and deserializing the state data. This has a number of uses, not just keeping state between sessions or page refreshes but also providing query facilities that help your application consume data.

If your application is connected then it may well have access to remote endpoints that will take care of the data storage for you. In this scenario a server-side db such as mongodb, rethinkdb or sqlserver is the usual way forward

if you are talking about a disconnected, browser only app then you can always serialize your state to `localStorage`. I do this frequently and I typically write a simple facade that allows me to 'query' the local data. If you need a more powerful local db then there are packages such as [localStorageDB](https://github.com/knadh/localStorageDB) out there to help.

Here is some code that shows how easy this can be:

**db.js**

This is a facade that sits on front of the localstorage package I use called [store](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js)

```
import store from 'store'

const clear = (key) => {
  if (key) {
    return store.remove(key)
  }
  store.clear()
}

const get = (key, defaultValue) => {
  return store.get(key) || defaultValue
}

const set = (key, value) => {
  store.set(key, value)
}

export { clear, get, set }
```

**transactions.js**

This is an example usage of the `db`. Here I get and set and clear sets of `transactions`

```
import * as db from './db'

const clear = () => {
  db.clear('transactions')
}

const transactions = value => {
  if (value) {
    db.set('transactions', value)
  } else {
    return db.get('transactions', [])
  }
}

export { clear, transactions }
```

Comment: Slightly off topic, but if you're persisting your application's data to the browser (presumably with the intent of it staying there permanently), localStorage isn't the best choice. You only get a maximum of 5MB storage per domain, and it's really easy for users to accidentally wipe their data. Long term data storage is much better suited to [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). You can kinda get the best of both worlds by using [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage), which provides a localStorage-like API with an IndexedDB backend.